# Send Files with TCP from client to server knowing file size Delphi

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy10

Hello im trying to send a file Via TCP with delphi using Indy Components with a Client/Server

i manage to send and recieve the files correctly, the problem is before sending the file i would like to send its size aswell to compare it after i get it the server.

Now im sending the files from the Client To Server.

Client:

```
Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Ms.LoadFromFile('cliente.exe');
  Ms.Position := 0;

  Result := True;
  Client.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
  try
    Client.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);// (Ms, 0, true);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
  Ms.Free;
```

Server:

```
 AStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\temp\file.exe', fmCreate + fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, -1,false);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(AStream);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('File received');
    end;
```

So the question would be how could i send the file size with the file?

Comment: use `Client.IOHandler.Write(ms.Size);` before sending the Memorystream and
 `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64;` before reading the Memorystream

Comment: Thx alot, i allready solved that with `TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(inttostr(Ms.Size));` and 
`sent_size:=strtoint(AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is **already** sending the file size. You are setting the `AWriteByteCount` parameter of `Write(TStream)` to True, which tells it to send the stream size before sending the stream data. And you are telling `ReadStream()` to read the stream size before reading the stream data. So Indy is already validating the size for you before `ReadStream()` exits. You don't need to do it manually at all.

Comment: I thought the same, but i tried and its not working i tried to cut the intermission before it ends and it just cuts, and doesnt give any error at all, it seems normal. thats why i was doing it manually

Comment: I assure you, what I described works just fine when used correctly. If you cut the transmission prematurely, the receiver will eventually get a socket read error and raise an exception. The sender MAY get a socket error, but it depends on whether the OS outbound buffer fills up or not. Remember, the OS, and thus the app, cannot detect *abnormal* disconnections in a timely manner, and will happily keep accepting data and buffering it until the disconnect is eventually detected.

Comment: You have to use heartbeats/keepalives to handle *abnormal* disconnects. At the very least, you should enable TCP-level keepalives, such as via `TIdSocketHandle.SetKeepAliveValues()`.

Comment: yes, you are right i wasnt just watching the except part and was doing too much, that why its really hard to be stupid :) thanks for the help